# Shifting of the summation question, unsure if author made a mistake

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

On a website discussing moment generating functions, the author includes the following as part of the discusion. My question is how does the author get from this:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{s^k}{k!} -1 \right) 
$$
To this:
$$
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!}
$$
The best I could come up with is:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{s^k}{k!} -1 \right) = \left(\frac{s^0}{0!} - 1\right) + \left(\frac{s^1}{1!} - 1\right) + \left(\frac{s^2}{2!} - 1\right) + \left(\frac{s^3}{3!} - 1\right) +  \text{(higher order terms)}
$$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!} = \frac{s^1}{1!} + \frac{s^2}{2!} + \frac{s^3}{3!} +  \text{(higher order terms)}
$$
It seems they are getting rid of an infinite number of $-1$'s, while shifting the index does nothing since the first term in the original equation $(\frac{s^0}{0!}-1)$ is equal to zero.

Comment: It's definitely a mistake and surely they just meant to write $\sum()-1$ rather than $\sum(-1)$

Answer (score 1):

My only guess is that the author ***meant***

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!} - 1 \text{ to mean } -1 + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!}$$

i.e. $-1$ is not inside the summation in actuality.

And then the reason why it holds is trivial: $k=0$ gives $1$, cancelling with the $-1$ outside.

---

The identity stated,

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \frac{s^k}{k!} - 1 \right)
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!}$$

is definitely false though. After all, for $s=0$, the left-hand side diverges, but the right hand side is $0$, just on inspection.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that there was a typographical error in the book regarding the nature of the parentheticals

Reindexing would give that :
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{s^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{s^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$$
However, it seems more likely that the logical step intended in the text was the following:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{s^k}{k!}=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!}\right) - \frac{s^0}{0!}=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!}\right) - 1$$